# cron job can't source functions from bashrc

Tags: cron

**crontab -e:**

30 22 * * 7 ~/bin/cron_run.sh

**~/bin/cron_run.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.bashrc
#run_this_function is defined in a script sourced by bashrc
run_this_function
```

`run_this_function` is not found. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `source ~/.bashrc` to `. ~/.bashrc`

That change will reload the contents of bashrc.

Then run_this_function should be available... if it is assigned properly as an alias.

Do you have the `run_this_function` declaration? - please post if you can.